# IOException: Unable to resolve host "URL": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android-asynctask, ftp, unknown-host

I am working on an android application. When I run the application on Sony mobile, it runs very well. When I use Huawei mobiles, it doesn't work, and is giving me this exception:

```
IOException: Unable to resolve host "URL": No address associated with hostname
```

Here are the permissions used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I have tried a number of things to fix this, but nothing has worked so far.

Any help on this would be appreciated.